# How to setup multinode EOS cluster on various vms

Tags: cleos, nodeos, node

How to setup multinode EOS cluster on lets say various aws/azure instances ? I have tried the multiple eos node deployment on single machine as described here - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/local-multi-node-testnet How to expand the similar setup to multiple machine multiple eos nodes ?

Comment: Maybe this guide can helps you: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/local-multi-node-testnet When starting nodeos, try to specify the ip address of your machine and not localhost

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. Please add some more information. E.g. what have you tried, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 - I have updated the question to what I have tried